# HttpClient.GetAsync() CPU consumption is high

Tags: c#, performance-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I have a service which uses HttpClient class to fetch some resources from other services. As part of our performance testing, we mocked the HttpClient.GetAsync() call in order to remove the dependencies from external services, and replaced it with a method which returns content from local disk. The thing which is surprising is the CPU utilization went from 65% to 22%. So, when the performance test was done without the mock, the CPU utilization was 65%, and with mock it decreased to 22%. **But the RPS remained constant**

Also, when i started increasing the load, the CPU utilization and the RPS went up, which i think is expected.

My question is - is HttpClient.GetAsync() such an expensive operation ? and if yes then how can i confirm this with performance analysis ? which tool can help me here.

Note: The performance test are run with 100 User Load per second using Visual Studio Load Testing Framework.

Thanks,
Javed

Comment: Have you actually used a profiler to see where the time is being taken?

Comment: You may increase the DefaultConnectionLimit of the HttpClient for your load tests : ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;

Comment: Also, be sure to use ConfigureAwait(false) when possible

Comment: does your mock class use thread.sleep?

Comment: @Ewan, Nope i am using Task.Delay in mock classes.

Comment: @Guillaume, can you give more details on ConfigureAwait(false), like can this be the reason of high CPU utilization ?

Comment: without ConfigureAwait(false) you use SynchronizationContext (if available) and that can increase CPU usage. For instance in WPF the thread switch can cost a lot if it's donne for thousands and thousands of `await`. Have you tried increasing the DefaultConnectionLimit ? Try setting it to 100 for instance.

Comment: my thought was that if your mock uses thread.sleep or possibly task.delay you are essentially freeing up processor cycles. the longer the delay the lower the cpu utilization. so you would expect the mock to use less cpu that the httpclient if they run at the same rate

Answer (score 0):

I typically construct my requests and use `HttpClient.SendAsync(request)` and rarely notice any spikes in CPU utilization. Also, 100 requests per second is a ton of requests. Consider re-designing your architecture so that it will perform better under heavy load. Things such as reducing the number of calls to `HttpClient.SendAsync` or `HttpClient.GetAsync` will improve your performance. You may also consider load balancing between an array of servers to reduce the response time and CPU load. Another consideration would be to cache responses to the external services that you interface with to reduce external HTTP calls. You could then rely on the cached response until the cache needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We cannot limit number of calls to HttpClient, as that could be the traffic on our site. Also, we are using cache techniques to improve the performance. We also have load balancing in place